# Execute state actions synchronously

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-statemachine

I am using a spring state machine with multiple regions, and I configure some region to have entryAction and exitAction.

I recently realized that the callback for the actions where run in a different thread and sometimes they don't complete until after the state transition is done.

Here's the stack trace for when the actions get scheduled:

```
    at org.springframework.statemachine.state.AbstractState.entry(AbstractState.java:208)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState.entry(ObjectState.java:156)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.entryToState(AbstractStateMachine.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.entryToState(AbstractStateMachine.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.setCurrentStateInternal(AbstractStateMachine.java:971)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.setCurrentState(AbstractStateMachine.java:949)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.setCurrentState(AbstractStateMachine.java:944)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.setCurrentStateInternal(AbstractStateMachine.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.setCurrentState(AbstractStateMachine.java:949)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.switchToState(AbstractStateMachine.java:841)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.access$400(AbstractStateMachine.java:77)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine$2.transit(AbstractStateMachine.java:301)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.handleTriggerTrans(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:248)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.processTriggerQueue(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:395)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.access$100(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor$1.run(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:281)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.scheduleEventQueueProcessing(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.execute(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.sendEventInternal(AbstractStateMachine.java:559)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.sendEvent(AbstractStateMachine.java:211)
```

To avoid race conditions and make sure that the state entry/exit actions are finished once the `sendEvent` function is done, I would like to use a Synchronous task scheduler, but I don't think there's such a thing (I would have to implement my own). Or is there another way to make sure my entry/exit actions are done after the transition?

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to use a Synchronous task scheduler, but I don't think
>   there's such a thing.

Yes, there is - Spring State Machine uses TaskExecutor for region executions and by default it's synchronous. And it looks like you are using it - you can see it in your stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
```

> Is there another way to make sure my entry/exit actions are done after
>   the transition?

Basically no - the transition "wraps" the *exit* action of the state you're exiting from and the *entry* action of the state you're entering in.

Actions in the SM are two types - *state* or *transition* actions. I assume you're talking about state entry/exit actions.
Here's the sequence order in which these types of actions are executed.

The below scenario is executed synchronously:

- two states `A` and `B`
- state entry and exit action on `A`, state entry and exit action on `B`
- transition action on the `A` -> `B` transition

The SM is positioned in state `A` - this means that the state entry action on `A` is already executed. We're sending an event, which triggers the transition from `A` -> `B`.

```
Transition started: from: A to: B
Action on transition from A to B //when transition starts, the transition action kicks in, before exiting state A
State A exit action on state //before exiting state A, the state A exit action kicks in  
State exited: A
State entered: B
State B entry action on state
Transition ended: from: A to: B
```

You can reproduce the same results, supplying a custom SM listener to the SM config.

Comment: There is a SyncTaskExecutor, but there isn't a SyncTaskScheduler (Executor != Scheduler). As you can see in the stack trace, my state entry/exit action are being dispatched to the task scheduler, which submits them on a different thread. This means the entry/exit actions are not guaranteed to be finished when the state transition function returns. 

So far the only way I found to solve the problem is to implement a very hacky synchronous task scheduler.

Comment: I believe there should be a guarantee, otherwise the SM will be non-deterministic. Yes - actions are wrapped in Runnable and queued in TaskScheduler, but there's transition and state actions errorHandlers - in my experience the transitions don't happen if there's error in some of the actions, so I guess there's a sync somewhere in the transition logic.

Comment: Yikes. I find this sequence of action execution very surprising. Being influenced by UML, I was expecting a sequence like so: all hierarchical exit actions (inner to outer), then transition action, then all entry actions (outer to inner).  See this description, section "Transition Execution Sequence" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Actions_and_transitions

Comment: @onouv not sure there's an actual difference, but last time I checked(2 years ago) Spring SM was based on https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF while wikipedia is referring to 2.2 version