# Unable to Trigger an Event from Action

Tags: java, spring-statemachine

I am setting up spring state-machine transactions, i want to launch Event2 on completion of Event1

These are the states i have

States -> "INITIAL", "SECOND", "THIRD"

I have configured the transactions to send SECOND_EVENT from action of FIRST_EVENT as shown below

```
transitions.withExternal()
    .source("INITIAL")
    .target("SECOND")
    .event("FIRST_EVENT")
    .action(new Action<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            System.out.println("FIRST_ACTION_EXECUTED");
            context.getStateMachine().sendEvent("SECOND_EVENT");
        }
    })
    .and()
    .withExternal()
    .source("SECOND")
    .target("THIRD")
    .event("SECOND_EVENT")
    .action(new Action<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            System.out.println("TEST SUCCESS");
        }
    });
```

Here i get evenNotAccepted exception, and i know the reason is that the statemachine.getState() is INITIAL, and it cant change the state from INITIAL to THIRD directly.

So my question is, Is there anyway that i can configure my statemachine to automatically trigger second event on completion of first event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the type of actions you're using.
There are two main types of actions in the Spring SM - *transition* actions and *state* actions - and they resolve on different times. You can see a sequence of resolving of those actions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56506436/1007273).

In order to fire events to go to your next state, you should use state actions.

You can configure state actions like so:

```
   builder.configureStates()
            .withStates()
            .initial(SI)
            .state(F1, context -> context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(E2))
            .state(F2, context -> context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(E3))
            .end(SF);

    builder.configureTransitions()
            .withExternal().source(SI).target(F1).event(E1)
            .and()
            .withExternal().source(F1).target(F2).event(E2)
            .and()
            .withExternal().source(F2).target(SF).event(E3)
                .action(context -> System.out.println("Completing SM!"));
```

Just firing event `E1` manually, will result in the following output (events `E2` and `E3` are auto-fired through state actions):

```
STATE ENTERED: SI
STAGE TRANSITIONS From: null To: SI
STATE EXITED: SI
STATE ENTERED: F1
STAGE TRANSITIONS From: SI To: F1
21:45:39.153 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine - Queue event GenericMessage [payload=E2, headers={id=393a5636-a760-57d6-a98b-d31eb75f048e, timestamp=1560969939152}] SF F2 F1 SI  / F1 / uuid=4e8773c1-e755-40de-b431-e53a4b0ca64d / id=null
STATE EXITED: F1
STATE ENTERED: F2
STAGE TRANSITIONS From: F1 To: F2
21:45:39.161 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine - Queue event GenericMessage [payload=E3, headers={id=f5899e8b-e4a5-e079-3a30-66114a7accac, timestamp=1560969939161}] SF F2 F1 SI  / F2 / uuid=4e8773c1-e755-40de-b431-e53a4b0ca64d / id=null
Completing SM!
STATE EXITED: F2
STATE ENTERED: SF
STAGE TRANSITIONS From: F2 To: SF
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am facing a different issue now, when i am configuring the states and sending events it works fine in DEBUG mode but when i run it in normal mode, it gives eventNotAccepted error sometimes, and sometimes it works fine.

So now i have changed it to:
            .initial(SI)
            .stateEntry(F1, context -> context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(E2))
            .stateEntry(F2, context -> context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(E3))
            .end(SF);

after changing to stateEntry it works as expected, but i want to now why does this happen

Comment: Oh I see, I guess it's because the actions are queued in a TaskExecutor and they are executed in a non sequential manner. The stateEntry are probably handled with some checks before executing, which ensures the order of execution.

Comment: So is it something similar to the thread scheduler, which we don't have any control on?

Comment: Yes it is, but I believe in the SM configuration you can supply your own TaskExecutor and TaskScheduler.

Comment: Okay, can you point in me the right direction as to where I can get more details about that please

Comment: sure, you can find more info in the configuring common settings -https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#statemachine-config-commonsettings