# How Spring state machine actions works

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I'm trying to do a complex task with Spring state machine! refers to the documentation state machines have 2 types of action, **step actions**, and **transaction actions**! events can be called from inside of state action!
but `s1()`, `s2()`, .. don't called! it seems `@EnableWithStateMachine` does not work correctly!

My configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class DeploySM {

    @Configuration
    @EnableStateMachineFactory
    @EnableWithStateMachine
    public static class Config extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<Manifest.Step, Manifest.Event> {
        @Override
        public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<Manifest.Step, Manifest.Event> states) throws Exception {
            super.configure(states);
            states.withStates().initial(Manifest.Step.INIT)
                    .state(Manifest.Step.S1 )
                    .state(Manifest.Step.S2)
                    .state(Manifest.Step.S3)
                    .state(Manifest.Step.S5)
                    .exit(Manifest.Step.S4);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<Manifest.Step, Manifest.Event> config) throws Exception {
            super.configure(config);
            config.withConfiguration()
                    .autoStartup(false);
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<Manifest.Step, Manifest.Event> transitions) throws Exception {
            super.configure(transitions);

            transitions.withExternal()
                    .source(Manifest.Step.INIT).target(Manifest.Step.S1)
                    .event(Manifest.Event.SUCCESS)
                    .and().withExternal()
                    .source(Manifest.Step.S1).target(Manifest.Step.S2)
                    .event(Manifest.Event.SUCCESS)
                    .and().withExternal()
                    .source(Manifest.Step.S1).target(Manifest.Step.S5)
                    .event(Manifest.Event.FAILED)

                    //
                    .and()
                    .withExternal()
                    .source(Manifest.Step.S2).target(Manifest.Step.S3)
                    .event(Manifest.Event.BUILD_SOURCE)
                    .and().withExternal()
                    .source(Manifest.Step.S2).target(Manifest.Step.S4)
                    .event(Manifest.Event.SUCCESS)
                    .and().withExternal()
                    .source(Manifest.Step.S2).target(Manifest.Step.FAILED)
                    .event(Manifest.Event.FAILED);
        }
```

State machine actions bean:

```java
@EnableWithStateMachine
    public static class DeploySMActionsBean {
        @Bean
        public DeploySMActions deploySM() {
            return new DeploySMActions();
        }
    }
```

State machine actions class:

```java
@WithStateMachine(name = "", id = "deploySM")
@Slf4j
public class DeploySMActions extends StateMachineActions {

    private Manifest manifest;

    @OnStateEntry(source = "INITIAL", target = "INIT")
    public void init() {
        manifest = new Manifest();
        log.info("init state: " + manifest.getUuid());
        sm.sendEvent(Manifest.Event.SUCCESS);
    }

    @OnStateEntry(source = "INIT", target = "S1")
    public void s1() {
        log.info("validate_config state: " + manifest.getUuid());
        sm.sendEvent(Manifest.Event.SUCCESS);
    }

    @OnStateEntry(source = "S1", target = "S2")
    public void s2() {
        log.info("create application");
        sm.sendEvent(Manifest.Event.FAILED);
    }

    //and other steps
}
```

Comment: See if this will give you clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674456/1007273

Comment: no I want to use @EnableWithStateMachine annotation and separate actions bean from state config class